# QGIS not recognizing special characters and problem with intersection?

Tags: intersection, qgis-2.18, utf-8

Started playing with QGIS recently and I have encountered a problem. I have a layer with administrative areas of my country and when adding it the encoding is set to UTF-8. When I open its attribute table the feature names are jumbled and special characters are replaced with symbols.
Also, when I try to use intersection with another layer i get the following message: Input layer A contains invalid geometries (feature 56). Unable to complete intersection algorithm.

I tried with 32 and 64 bit version of QGIS 2.18.9. I'm running Windows 10. 
The catch is, a friend of mine is using QGIS 2.14.2 on Windows 10, and didn't have any problems with encoding (her attribute tables are fine) or intersection (works without any error messages) while using the same SHP files.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you zoomed to feature 56? It is likely to contain some topology errors like self intersections. Some algorithms deal better with these topology errors, try to use another algorithm in the processing toolbox, try the SAGA intersect tool. As for the encoding, try another one: system or ISO-8859-1

Comment: As far as I see there are no features labeled with number 56.

Using the system encoding works. Thank you.
Afterwards the intersection works, but the layer is empty, yay.

Comment: I jumped to conclusion, the intersection still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried the intersect from SAGA? (Processing > Toolbox > type:intersect)

Comment: Ok, so I tried using SAGA intersect tool and it worked like a charm. I just have to merge all the polygons in the intersect layer into one to avoid double entries. Thank you Albert.

I suppose that means that my problem is solved, but I'd be really grateful if somebody could explain why this happened so I can avoid similar problems in future.